Optomize query for postgresql with index on jsonb array
I have tables:

request(id: int, current_stage_id: int, selection_id: int)
selection(id: int, settings: jsonb)

Settings has array like {id: int, stage_type: int}.
For example: [{id: 1, stage_type: 2}, {id: 2, stage_type: 5}]
I need query for request if current_stage_id belongs some stage type. There is many selection and many requests - so I need use index or else.
I created index - but it is not used.
CREATE INDEX ix_selection_stage_setting ON selection USING gin (settings jsonb_path_ops);
The current request looks like this:
with stage_settings as (SELECT stage.id as stage_id, stage.stage_type, rs.id as selection_id
FROM selection rs,
jsonb_to_recordset(rs.settings) AS stage(id INT, stage_type INT))
SELECT r.id, r.selection_id, r.current_stage_id 
FROM request r
JOIN stage_settings ss on ss.stage_id = r.current_stage_id AND ss.selection_id = r.selection_id
WHERE ss.stage_type = 1;

I need to change it to use an index or other optimization. MATERIALIZED VIEW was rejected by a senior employee.

The data model is horrible. That's what you get if you store arrays of key-value pairs instead of modeling that in a relational way.
Your query as it is has no chance of performing well.
If you rewrite the query as follows, it has a chance of being faster if request is not too large:
SELECT r.id, r.selection_id, r.current_stage_id
FROM request AS r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT FROM selection AS rs
              WHERE r.selection_id = rs.id
                AND rs.settings @> jsonb_build_array(
                                      jsonb_build_object(
                                         'id', r.current_stage_id,
                                         'stage_type', 1
                                      )
                                   )
             );

In addition to your GIN index, you should also have one on selection.id (if it isn't already your primary key).
If selection is small, the following version might be better:
SELECT DISTINCT
       r.id, r.selection_id, r.current_stage_id
FROM request AS r
   JOIN selection AS rs
      ON r.selection_id = rs.id
         AND rs.settings @> jsonb_build_array(
                               jsonb_build_object(
                                  'id', r.current_stage_id,
                                  'stage_type', 1
                               )
                            );


@> not wirking with array json. So I have to do like this in condition
EXISTS (select * from (SELECT rs.id, jsonb_array_elements(settings) as array_json
FROM selection AS rs
WHERE r.selection_id = rs.id) as a
WHERE array_json @> jsonb_build_object('id', r.current_stage_id, 'stage_type', 1))

but it still not using index

I fixed my answer; I had forgotten the array. It may well be that PostgreSQL is still not using the index, because using the index wouldn't help. I'd expect PostgreSQL to use the index in a nested loop join if request is small, but selection is large. Otherwise, you may be out of luck, and there is no query that can perform decently with a data model like this.
